# React App with SS3 Hosted on S3, Lambda, and Express

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, server-side-rendering, serverless-framework

I have a production React app that I am trying to host using Lambda, S3, and Express. There is really one goal: Before the static files are served, I want to make some edits to the `index.html` file including updating the favicon based on the subdomain, etc. Then I'd like to serve the rest of the static files as is. I am using serverless with no luck. The result is just an empty white page when I click on the Lambda URL.

`app.ts`

```
const getStaticFolder = async (): Promise<S3.GetObjectOutput> => {
  const s3Bucket = new S3({
    accessKeyId: getEnvVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY"),
    secretAccessKey: getEnvVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
    region: getEnvVariable("AWS_REGION"),
  });

  const params: S3.GetObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: "platter-customer-web",
    Key: `static`,
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3Bucket.getObject(params, (err: Error, data: S3.GetObjectOutput) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

const app: Express = express();

app.use("/static", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const staticBuild = await getStaticFolder();

  res.send(staticBuild);
});

app.use("*", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const indexFile = await getIndexFileFromS3();
  const indexText = indexFile.Body?.toString("utf-8") as string;

  const newIndex = getReplacedTags(indexText);

  return res.send(newIndex);
});

export const handler = serverless(app);
```

`serverless.yml`

```
service: sample-app
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  memorySize: 512
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
functions:
  app:
    handler: app.handler
    events: 
      - http: 
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
      - http: 
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
```

I can't seem to get the `/static` route to work & not sure I'm going about this the right way. Essentially, there's an s3 bucket with a static web app. I just want to serve the files from there, while editing the `index.html` before serving.